# PHP 5.6 : Same session being assgined to another user (incorrect login and many other problems)

Tags: php, session

The system is opencart, but anyway, I describe the condition.

Currently my site has a daily visit of around 500 unique visitors. From some time ago, I started getting complaints that a user has logged in but has seen that she/he has indeed being logged into another user's account.  What comes to my mind is that the session id of the victim customer is assigned to the new one. Anyway, what is confusing to me:

1- The number of visitors are not as high as to cause duplication of session IDs.
2- It happened suddenly.

I use Nginx and Apache (nginx as reverse proxy), files session handler and php-fpm. Just to give extra info.

In my php.ini, entropy length is 32 and it is set to use /dev/urandom.

Also, I pasted the stupid, simple opencart's session.php library file:

```
class Session {
    public $data = array();
    public function __construct($session_id = '',  $key = 'default') {
        if (!session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');
            if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,40}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
                exit();
            }
            if ($session_id) {
                session_id($session_id);
            }
            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
            session_start();
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = array();
        }
        $this->data =& $_SESSION[$key];
    }
    public function getId() {
        return session_id();
    }
    public function start() {
        return session_start();
    }
    public function destroy() {
        return session_destroy();
    }
}
```

It has confused me for several days, to no avail.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce? Could you confirm the claims? You say "a" user, to how many people did this happen to? Could you correlate it to any changes in the system/application (i.e. did it start happening after some specific deployment)?

Comment: It's happening for a number of users. Maybe 5% or 10%. It's hard to reproduce it, but once it also happened to myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, it might work for the future users. The problem had nothing to do with OpenCart, but the php's configuration.

Since I changed the php's session save path, the default php gc (garbage collector) did not work (as documented in offical PHP documentation, if save path gets changed, you are responsible for cleaning the garbage sessions) did not cleaned the session. After setting my own gc (a php scripts which removes the garbage sessions), the problem got solved.

I wrote a php script which checks the last modification date of the session and checks it against the session lifetime (expiration time), if passed, then remove the files. The script is scheduled to be run every 5 minutes.